# MongooseJS FindById ObjectId

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have this simple schema:

```
var CategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    description: String
});
```

I get id as URL parameter:

```
var id = req.params.id;
Category.findById(id, function(err, blogshop){
...
});
```

Do I need to use `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;` or passing the `hex` value is ok? Thanks

Comment: A string will be casted to `ObjectId`.

Answer (score 1):

from the [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById)

```
id <ObjectId, HexId> objectid, or a value that can be casted to one
```

you can simply put string of id